# How do I pass a string to HashSet contains?

Tags: string, rust, hashset, borrowing

I want to use a `HashSet` for quick string lookup, but I can't seem to find a way to pass a string variable to `contains` without a compiler error.

```
refs = HashSet::new();

let first_pass = link_regex.replace_all(&buffer, |caps: &Captures| {

    if caps.len() == 2 {
        refs.insert(caps.at(2).unwrap());
    }

    caps.at(1).unwrap().to_owned()
});

let out = ref_regex.replace_all(&first_pass, |caps: &Captures| {
    let capture = caps.at(1).unwrap().to_owned();

    // only remove if we've seen it before
    if refs.contains(capture) {
        return "".to_string();
    }

    capture
});
```

That causes this error:

```
 src/bin/remove_links.rs:30:26: 30:33 error: mismatched types [E0308]
 src/bin/remove_links.rs:30         if refs.contains(capture) {
                                                     ^~~~~~~
 src/bin/remove_links.rs:30:26: 30:33 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
 src/bin/remove_links.rs:30:26: 30:33 note: expected type `&_`
 src/bin/remove_links.rs:30:26: 30:33 note:    found type `std::string::String`
```

If I try

```
refs.contains(&capture)
```

then I get

```
src/bin/remove_links.rs:30:17: 30:25 error: the trait bound `&str: std::borrow::Borrow<std::string::String>` is not satisfied [E0277]
src/bin/remove_links.rs:30         if refs.contains(&capture) {
                                           ^~~~~~~~
```

I'm stumped, do I need to do some sort of type cast?

Comment: Could you add the `// put stuff in refs` part? It's actually more or less important for this question.

Comment: Plase add a complete example we can try to compile.  It sounds like you've got a `HashSet<&str>` instead of `HashSet<String>`, which as @LukasKalbertodt says would be from how you initialise `refs`.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I've added where I'm inserting strings. So I take it there's more I need to do at `HashSet` initialization...

Comment: @ray no the initialization is fine, but it's important to find out a few things. Look at my answer to understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Explanation

First, let's find out what type `refs` has. At the point `HashSet::new()`, the compiler can't tell what kinds of things you are going to put into the set, so the type is not clear yet. But the compiler figures it out in this line:

```
refs.insert(caps.at(2).unwrap());
```

The expression inside the function call (`caps.at(2).unwrap()`) returns a `&str`. So we are putting `&str`s into the set, thus `refs` has the type `HashSet<&str>`.

If you now look at the [documentation for `contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.contains), you see that it takes some `&Q` as argument. There are also some bounds: `where T: Borrow<Q>, Q: Hash + Eq`. We can ignore the `Hash + Eq` part; it doesn't cause any problems.

So let's focus on the `T: Borrow<Q>`. We do know what `T` is: `&str`. So let's see what `impl` of `Borrow` there are for `&str`: [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html). We'll find many generic impls, the important of which are (removed some noise):

- `impl<T> Borrow<T> for T`
- `impl<T> Borrow<T> for &T`

So pattern matching our `&str` with the right hand pattern, we conclude that for `&str`, `Borrow<&str>` and `Borrow<str>` are implemented. So our `Q` could be `str` for example. That means that `contains` receives a parameter of type `&str` (remember the `&Q` from above).

`capture` however, is of type `String`. `&capture` is an expression of type `&String`. Whenever such an expression is used in a position where a `&str` is needed without doubt, the compiler knows how to turn `&String` into `&str` (deref coercion). In this case however, the situation is not that clear, since we take a detour through the `Borrow` trait. Therefore we have to explicitly convert the `String` into a `&str`. There are a quazzilion ways to achieve this, but how about [`as_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str)? So the ...

#### Working solution

```
if refs.contains(capture.as_str()) {
    // ...
}
```